# safe option in django templates

Tags: html, django, django-templates

I am trying to print a html tag in django template using `safe` option in django templates.
I am using it like below.

```
  {{ message|safe }}
```

It works fine as long as I have only one tag ,

for example If I have to print below, it works fine.

```
<div class="message">data</div>
```

But If I have another tag inside `div` , it is not generated as raw html, rather it is generated as below.

```
<div class="message">&lt;img src=&quot;/media//uploads/Capture_16.PNG&quot; /&gt;</div>
```

I would like it to be generated as

```
<div class="message"><img src="/media//uploads/Capture_16.PNG" /></div>
```

What options do I have to achieve this ?

**EDIT**

Below is the original message without using `safe`or any kind of escaping.

```
&lt;div class=&quot;message&quot;&gt;data&lt;/div&gt;

&lt;div class=&quot;message&quot;&gt;&amp;lt;img src=&amp;quot;/media//uploads/Capture_16.PNG&amp;quot; /&amp;gt;&lt;/div&gt;
```

Comment: Your `message` context variable apparently contains already escaped HTML, otherwise `{{ message|safe }}` would do exactly what you want.

Comment: so can I escape it again ? locally ?

Comment: No, your problem is that `message` is _already_ escaped, and you cannot "unescape" it. `|safe` only turns off automatic escaping done at template render time, but the variable needs to be non-escaped for that to work. Without knowing how you compose your `message` variable in your view, it is impossible to tell why it is already escaped in the first place.